# How to call a recipe from custom handler in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

For invoking any recipe, the "include_recipe" method is used.  I have created an exception handler where I am calling a rollback recipe.  However, it is not working.  The following is my code:

```
require 'chef/log'
require 'time'

module TEST
  class ExceptionHandler < Chef::Handler
    def report      
      if run_status.failed? then
        Chef::Log.info("Running Report handler for failed client run...")        
        Chef::Log.info("Formatted Exception: "+run_status.formatted_exception)
        //here i want to call rollback recipe
        include_recipe "TEST::rollback"
      else
        Chef::Log.info("Running success...")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The log file contains the following:

- "Running report handler for failed client run"
- "Formatted exception"

However I did not find anything in the log file mentioning the rollback recipe.

Is the code I have used above for invoking a recipe correct?

Comment: Please show your code and restate your question.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: When you say "it is not working", you need to provide more detail.  Are you sure the exception handler is being called? Are you sure the `TEST` module is being called?  Have you put in `print` statements into them to make sure they are being called?  How do you simulate a failed `run_status` in your test?

Comment: I found the logging statements "Running Report handler for failed client run..." and "Formatted Exception:" in log file. However i didn't find any logging statement related to rollback recipe. In general, the way i used for invoking recipe in above code is correct or not?

Comment: I have incorporated your comments into the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the point that a handler has been called, Chef as already finished its execution. You would have to create a custom execution context for this to work. Take a look at the poise cookbook and its implementation of include_recipe to see how to do this, but I highly recommend not doing so given the complexity involved and how fragile the resulting system will be.